# No runtime coverage using emma, junit and ant

Tags: java, ant, junit, emma

I have the following project structure:

- src/com/dummy/abc.java
- src_tests/come/dummy/abcTest.java
- build.xml

I need to check the coverage of my code done by tests using emma.
From reading the emma + junit examples i came to a conclusion that to get a report i need to do the following:

1. compile 'src'
2. compile 'src_tests'
3. instrument compiled 'src_tests' => 'instrumented_src_tests'
4. run junit on 'instrumented_src_tests' with additional jvmarg

The problem is that the step 4 should return some kind of a file which then used with 'report' command should create a report. I'm getting

```
emma-report:
   [report] processing input files ...
   [report] 1 file(s) read and merged in 67 ms
   [report] nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files
```

~ edit
i'm attaching my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project name="HELL scream" default="all" basedir=".">
    <property name="build.sources.dir" location="${basedir}/src"/>
    <property name="build.sources.des" location="${basedir}/bin/classes"/>
    <property name="test.sources.dir" location="${basedir}/src_test"/>
    <property name="test.sources.des" location="${basedir}/bin/classes_test"/>
    <property name="test.reports.des" location="${basedir}/reports-junit"/>
    <property name="emma.sources.des" location="${basedir}/bin/classes_emma"/>
    <property name="emma.reports.des" location="${basedir}/reports-emma"/>
    <property name="emma.final.reports.des" location="${basedir}/reports-emma/final"/>
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <path id="emma.lib" >
        <fileset dir="/home/user1/Desktop/emma-2.0.5312/lib">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <taskdef resource="emma_ant.properties" classpathref="emma.lib" />
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <target name="clean-all">
        <delete failonerror="false">
            <fileset dir="${emma.final.reports.des}"/>
            <fileset dir="${emma.reports.des}"/>
            <fileset dir="${emma.sources.des}"/>
            <fileset dir="${test.reports.des}"/>
            <fileset dir="${test.sources.des}"/>
            <fileset dir="${build.sources.des}"/>
        </delete>
    </target>
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <target name="compile-sources">
        <mkdir dir="${build.sources.des}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${build.sources.dir}" includes="" excludes="" destdir="${build.sources.des}" listfiles="true" debug="true" includeantruntime="false"/>
    </target>  
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->   
    <target name="compile-tests">
        <mkdir dir="${test.sources.des}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${test.sources.dir}" includes="" excludes="" destdir="${test.sources.des}" listfiles="true" debug="true" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="/home/user1/Desktop/junit-4.10.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${build.sources.des}"/>
            </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target> 
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <target name="compile-emma-tests">
        <emma enabled="true" >
            <instr instrpath="${test.sources.des}" destdir="${emma.sources.des}" metadatafile ="${emma.reports.des}/instrumentation.emma" merge ="true"/>
        </emma>
    </target>
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ --> 
    <target name="run-tests">
        <mkdir dir="${test.reports.des}"/>
        <junit haltonfailure="no" showoutput="yes" printsummary="true">            
            <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="/home/user1/Desktop/junit-4.10.jar"/>
                <pathelement location="${build.sources.des}"/>  
                <pathelement location="${emma.sources.des}"/>                
                <path refid="emma.lib" />
            </classpath>

            <batchtest todir="${test.reports.des}" fork="true">
                <fileset dir="${emma.sources.des}"/>
            </batchtest>                       

            <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${emma.reports.des}/coverage.emma" />
            <jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false" />
        </junit>            
    </target>
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <target name="junit-tests-report">
        <junitreport todir="${test.reports.des}">
            <fileset dir="${test.reports.des}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
           </fileset>

           <report format="frames" todir="${test.reports.des}/junit_reports"/>
       </junitreport>
    </target> 
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <target name="emma-tests-report">
        <emma enabled="true" >
            <report sourcepath="${build.sources.dir}">    
                <fileset dir="${emma.reports.des}" >
                    <include name="*.emma" />
                </fileset>

                <txt outfile="${emma.final.reports.des}/coverage.txt" depth="package" columns="class,method,block,line,name" />
                <xml outfile="${emma.final.reports.des}/coverage.xml" depth="package" />
                <html outfile="${emma.final.reports.des}/coverage.html" depth="method" columns="name,class,method,block,line" />
            </report>
        </emma>
    </target>
    <!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->
    <target name="all" depends="clean-all, compile-sources, compile-tests, compile-emma-tests, run-tests, junit-tests-report, emma-tests-report"/>
</project>
```

it is probably something trivial...

also, when using emma.sources.dest 
i'm getting this on my (only) test

```
run-tests:
    [junit] Running com.emma.test.MathTest
    [junit] Testsuite: com.emma.test.MathTest
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] 
    [junit]     Caused an ERROR
    [junit] Illegal local variable table length 5 in method com.emma.test.MathTest.<init>()V
    [junit] java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal local variable table length 5 in method com.emma.test.MathTest.<init>()V
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    [junit]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    [junit] 
    [junit] Test com.emma.test.MathTest FAILED
```

~ SOLVED
add this:

```
<jvmarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"/>
<jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.file=${emma.reports.des}/coverage.emma" />
<jvmarg value="-Demma.coverage.out.merge=false" />
```

Comment: did you follow this to setup emma with ant http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide/ar01s03.html

Comment: yes. (And many more). Besides, information located in that link does not tell how to use it with junit, but pure java.

Answer (score 3):

Emma hasn't had a stable release since 2005, and doesn't play well with newer versions of the JDKs. Cobertura hasn't done any new development since [2011](http://sourceforge.net/p/cobertura/code/795/log/?path=/trunk).
Because of that, I no longer recommend to developers to use Emma or Cobertura.

I've switched to [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/index.html) for code coverage. It was started by the Emma Eclipse team, and is actively being developed.

As stated in JaCoCo's [mission statement](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/mission.html).

> [...]Two of the best and widely used available open source tools are EMMA and Cobertura. Both tools are not actively maintained by the original authors any more and do not support the current Java versions. Due to the lack of regression tests maintenance and feature additions is difficult.
>
> Therefore we started the JaCoCo project to provide a new standard technology for code coverage analysis in Java VM based environments. [...]

The nice thing about JaCoCo is that it works in a wide variety of environments, and you don't have to instrument your code after compiling. The instrumentation takes place as the tests are being executed. It looks something like this:

```
<jacoco:coverage destfile="${target.dir}/jacoco.exec">
    <junit>
        [...]
    </junit>
</jacoco>
```

You then use `<jacoco:coverage>` to print the coverage report.

Do you have to use Emma? If not, you might better luck getting everything working using JaCoCo.

Answer (score 1):

Emma relies upon bytecode injection (if memory serves me well); but, with Java 7, the code hasn't been updated because the JVM now has a debugging interface.

JaCoCo tests code coverage by attaching to the debugging interface and listening as your code enters methods and passes over the bytecode without injecting checkpoints.  It's clearly the superior way to do things (now that it exists) and I doubt that Emma will do the work to fully support Java 7.

I suggest that you "upgrade" to JaCoCo.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when you use wrong command to generate the report.
Most of the online tutorial is advocating the wrong(may by old) command, even I got this error when I used below command to generate the report:

{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext>java -cp emma.jar emma report -r html -in coverage.em, {ALFRESCO_HOME}\coverage.ec
EMMA: processing input files ...
EMMA: 1 file(s) read and merged in 60 ms
EMMA: nothing to do: no runtime coverage data found in any of the data files

Correct usage of the command is:
**{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext>java -cp emma.jar emma report -r txt,html -in {JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage.em -in C:\t1_tempSetup\Alfresco\coverage.ec**
EMMA: processing input files ...
EMMA: 2 file(s) read and merged in 70 ms
EMMA: writing [txt] report to [{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage.txt] ...
EMMA: writing [html] report to [{JAVA_HOME}\jre\lib\ext\coverage\index.html] ...